# Is there a word that means exactly physically carrying things (baggage, person etc.) on the head or shoulders?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, idioms

Example sentence

Bill ____ the demon.

Single word (verb) is better, two words (VP) are okay. The word has to mean carrying something physically on the head or shoulders.

Comment: If you _shoulder_ something, you hoist it onto your shoulder(s) to carry. Carrying things on the head is unusual enough in most English-speaking cultures not to have a single-word term.

Comment: Do you mean like a rucksack or balanced on the top of head or like carrying a pole/gun/bindle over one shoulder, or bearing on one shoulder like a brick hod, or like a yoke around the neck of an animal?

Comment: Like a bag or some other heavy object. Like carrying the world's weight on one's shoulder. Is there any single word that expresses this "carrying something  on shoulder"?

Comment: *shoulder* means to put something on your shoulder, it doesn't refer to the continuous act of carrying after you hoist it. Also, this can be confused with other senses of the word.

Comment: I can't think of a word for this.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a single word/verb that can be used both for carrying on the head or shoulders. There are separate verbs for carrying on the head and carrying on the shoulders.

There is simply ***shoulder (v.)*** for carrying on the shoulders. *OED* definition of this sense:

> *transitive.* To support with, bear up or carry on the shoulder or shoulders; to take or place on one's shoulder to be carried. Also *spec.* of a racehorse, to carry (a specified weight) on the back.

There are the verbs ***head-carry*** and ***head-load*** for carrying on the head. *OED* definition of *head-carry*:

> **head-carry**  *v. transitive* to carry (a load) on one's head; = *head-load vb.*

Wikipedia's [*Head-carrying*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-carrying) article is useful also.

Comment: "Head-carry" is actually used. I will use shoulder-carry, though there is no entry for it in the dictionaries. Thank you very much.

Comment: @banuyayi   I gather from your example, which involves a demon, that the genre of what you're writing affords an author a good deal of liberty, but in situations where you are expected to be use idiomatic (well-established, commonly used) language, if you wanted to say unambiguously that someone *literally* shouldered a burden, a phrase would be more suitable than the verb **shoulder-carry**:  *He carried the burden on his shoulder*.